# Mariadb: Can I increase performance by having multiple column indexes with different orders?

Tags: performance, index, mariadb, index-tuning

In my Mariadb table I have two id-columns (A,B), which combined are unique, but not individually. This table is quite large. To speed up queries like

```
SELECT B WHERE A=?
```

I have added a primary key (A,B), which worked fine. However sometimes I also need queries

```
SELECT A WHERE B=?
```

which are rather slow. What is the optimal way improve performance here? Is it reasonable to create a second unique index (B,A) on the table?

Moreover, if I do create that second index, does inserting entries into the table become slower, since both indexes are checked? In theory, checking that (A,B) is unique implies that (B,A) is unique, but does Mariadb know that, or does it check both?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it reasonable to create a second unique index (B,A) on the table?

Yes, since your predicate in the `WHERE` clause in the second query is on column `B` and your original index that leads with column `A` (i.e. `(A, B)`) won't be able to be seeked through for this query. So you currently are probably experiencing a less than performant index scan.

> Moreover, if I do create that second index, does inserting entries into the table become slower...

Yes.

> ...since both indexes are checked?

Not so much because of redundant checking for uniqueness, more so it's because of the additional write-overhead there is to maintain two indexes now. But generally that overhead is rather negligible unless you're writing *millions of records a second*, for example.

There is a general balance though between not enough indexes and too many. It depends on the query use cases, the read vs write workload, the infrastructure behind the database server, and what's acceptable runtimes all around. Typically, up to 5 indexes on a table are fine, and up to 5 columns per index (for being cognizant of index width) is fine. But it's a very loose guideline, and sometimes less or more is the correct number for a specific table's use cases.

Comment: I think the second index doesn't need to be unique since that logical constraint is already handled by the first one

Comment: @user20042973 Yes, probably true. Though some database systems have minor performance optimizations when reading from an index that has a unique specification defined on it. Not sure if MariaDB does, and generally it's very minor. Again, that's not really the overhead concern anyway.

Comment: @user20042973 Making it unique usually does get better insert performance, but also for `SELECT` queries not every optimizer is able to infer uniqueness from a different index than the one being queried.

Comment: Interesting, the read optimizations make sense. Today I learned about potential _insert_ performance improvements as well, I naively would have guessed the opposite. Thank you both

Comment: @Charlieface - No.  When `INSERTing`, _all_ Unique indexes must be checked before returning to the client.  Non-unique secondary indexes can be delayed and performed in the background (cf the "Change buffer").

Comment: @J.D. - In my experience, the slowdown in  `INSERT` is not worth worrying about, especially for non-Unique indexes.  I concur with your "5 indexes, 5 columns".  Another:  3 or more UNIQUEs is a red flag.

Comment: @RickJames OK that's a MariaDB specific thing. In most systems, every index is fundamentally unique on some level (In SQL Server by adding a uniquifier for non-unique indexes) so it makes little difference. The extra performance would come from not needing to check for the uniquifier. And on most systems all indexes are written using the same system: normal Write Ahead Logging.

Comment: @Charlieface - For MariaDB, the "uniquifier" in the index is the column(s) of the `PRIMARY KEY`.  I don't think there is "Write Ahead Logging".

Comment: @RickJames Interesting, that makes sense, so in this case the primary key is already in the index. Almost all RDBMSs use a WAL under pessimistic concurrency, see eg https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-undo-log/

Comment: I think InnoDB uses optimistic.  Does the undo log sound like WAL?